# How do I disable the new device notification on my Gmail account?

Tags: security, google-account

Each and every time I sign in to a Gmail account, I get a notification with "New sign-in from Firefox on Windows".

Moreover, I have another Gmail account which I sign in to on the same computer and I do not know why but I get the notification of the sign-in of the second account on the first account!

Long story short, every time I sign in to either the first account or the second one, I get a notification [a message] in the first account.

**How can I disable this annoying notification?**

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Do you use a VPN? Clear your browser cookies? Sign in from multiple networks? When Google doesn't recognize where you're signing in from it sends one of these messages just in case. I don't see a way to turn this off. It's a security feature, after all. You _could_ create a Gmail filter to delete them automatically, but I wouldn't recommend that. If someone were to hack your account you'd lose this important alert.

Comment: Lots of information at https://myaccount.google.com/security

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Anyway, I just sign in with more than accounts on the same computer, same IP, same location.
Why do I receive this alert on the first account but when it is the contrary, I do not receive it on the other account?! Don't get it....
in the options there is a section with the edit of the alert settings but it can either for email or phone and there is no way to disable it completely! It is since I created the other account that I receive all these notifications ...it wasn't like that, before.